# How to wire SqlMapClientFactoryBean a dataSource in spring.xml config file

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean name="ibatis" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" value="myDataSource" />
</bean>
```

this config always wrong, says cannot convert myDataSource to a real datasource object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myDataSource` is a bean, so should be injected by reference using `ref` attribute, instead of `value`:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
```